# How to find if string contain on the variable which has contents of file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

couldn't find a specific string on a variable containing file content

```
#!/bin/bash

core_pattern=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern)
apport_full_path="/usr/share/apport/apport"


if [[ $(grep "$apport_full_path" "$core_pattern") ]] ; then
   echo "Found"
else
   echo "Not Found"
fi


grep: |/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P: No such file or directory
Not Found
```

I expect an output of "Found" or "Not Found" but ending up with an error

Comment: That really helped. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a file into a variable and then run `grep`, this approach is bit redundant:

```
#!/bin/bash

core_pattern=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern)
apport_full_path="/usr/share/apport/apport"


if  grep -q "$apport_full_path" <<< "$core_pattern"  ; then
   echo "Found"
else
   echo "Not Found"
fi
```

OR, better, run `grep` over the file itself, why to store to a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern_file="/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern"
apport_full_path="/usr/share/apport/apport"


if  grep -q "$apport_full_path" "$pattern_file"  ; then
   echo "Found"
else
   echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Generally `grep` is used like:

```
grep <string to search> <file_to_seaarch>
```

or

```
grep <string_to_Search> <<< "${variable_to_search}"
```